# Module vs. Dependency vs. Library vs. Package vs. Component

Tags: node.js, npm, module, dependencies, package

I understand that packages hold several modules, but I'm starting to get confused as to if packages and modules are dependencies. Also, libraries to me maybe seem like packages you install via NPM, Nuget, RubyGems, Bower, Homebrew, or Chocolatey. So are libraries packages? Dependencies are something you need to load within your application, to have a certain functionality, but aren't some libraries(jQuery) seen as a dependency? So yea, what are the differences between these concepts?

Comment: maybe there are set definitions but it’s a question of an individuals interpretation as well so the way i see it is a library is a collection of packages where a package is a collection of modules and a module is a collection of components ... now a dependency is anyone of these things where one piece of code depends on another.. in nodejs terminology maybe there are specific definitions but this is how i would break it down in the general case

Comment: @mad.meesh Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @mad.meesh sounds like the answer

Answer (score 7):

Libraries are just a bunch of code anyone can use. For example, React.js is a JavaScript library for building front end components.

If I decide to use this library in my app, then React will become one of the modules (*aka an installed instance of the library*) that my app depends on. So dependencies are pretty much all of the libraries your app depends on, in order to run the way you expect it to run.

I asked the same question you did about dependencies, and I learned that it's a matter of understanding how these terms relate to one another rather than finding isolated definitions for each of them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Basically a **package** is a pack with some features which fullfills some functionality of your app.

Once you install any package using **npm** then the package is installed as a **dependency** in your app inside your **package.json** file along with its **modules**(aka **libraries** consist of classes) stored inside **node_modules** folder.

I hope its clear now.

Comment: So packages aka dependences like React go into package.json, and modules (parts of those libraries you use go into node_modules folder)?

Comment: @cheznead exactly!

Comment: @cheznead; actually a package only becomes dependency when installed and/or required in a system/app